# Way to asynchronously load SharePoint profile images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, image-processing

I'm working on a sharepoint farm that has User Profiles enabled. We're creating a community feature which has a profile wall of all members of that community. I need to retrieve and display profile pictures from a search based source and display the results as they are returned in an appealing efficient way.

We have two avenues:

1: FAST search indexes the profiles of every user every 6 hours. We can run a membership query and return all members of [x] community.

2: We can use the profile API to do a search. This is slower but does not rely on the 6 hour index and therefore gives us up to date information.

We need to make this call via JavaScript, as sever side code is locked down and not an option. I'd like to write a function that calls these profiles and loads the images into a wall one at a time as they are retrieved. Possibly in a timed loop, so an image loads every 100 milliseconds.

I believe profile photos are stored as a text property containing the photo URL, so the URL can be set as an images source.

How would I go about quickly loading a set of images asynchronously to provide a good user experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have server side code option, I would suggest you to go for a Jquery Script which would render these images. This javascript code can be loaded asynchronously as suggested in this article:

https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+load+JavaScript+dynamically+with+jQuery

Comment: I think that's all the feedback I'm going to get on this one. Answer for trying :)